# How to assign values from returned list from AppleScript script to variables in Automator?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, automator

In my Automator action, I use an "Run AppleScript" action, that returns a list (via AppleScript). Here is the AppleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set result to {"Foo", "Bar", "42"}
    return result
end run
```

Later in my Automator action, I need to use values `"Foo"`, `"Bar"`, and `"42"` in different places.

How can I assign those 3 values to different Automator variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your question literally, you have to first set the result of the **Run AppleScript** *action*, which in this case is a `list`, to a **Set Value of Variable** *action*.

Next, you'd add a **Get Value of Variable**<sup>1</sup>  *action*. setting its **Options** to **[√] Ignore this actions input** so as to make a disconnect from the **Set Value of Variable** *action*.

Next, add a **Run AppleScript** *action* with the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return item 1 of input
end run
```

Then add a **Set Value of Variable** *action* for this first item in the `list` returned from to original **Run AppleScript** *action*.

Repeat again for the next two *items* in the `list`.

[image: Automator workflow]

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Technically you could send the output of the first **Set Value of Variable** *action* directly to the second **Run AppleScript** *action* to set the first `list` *item* to it new *variable*; however, I broke it into a separate *action* so the creation of the three `list` *items* as separate *variables* followed the same *action* path.</sub>

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z1oq.png) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).

Comment: Thank you, your answer made the concept a lot more clear for me. Makes you appreciate AppleScript and Automator — they are really powerful tools.